# Understanding of Recursive Method (Permutations)

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

As the title states I'm looking for a little help understanding what is happening in the attached code. Specifically, why are there are quotation marks in the '("", s)'
What is going on with (String s1, String s2), is this where the letters are being instantiated?

Lastly, what exactly is happening in the bottom displayPermutaion equation?

Thank you for taking the time to help, I really do appreciate it!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        System.out.print("Please enter your phrase here: ");
        String s = new Scanner(System.in).next();
        System.out.println("All the permutations of your phrase are listed below:\n" + s);

        displayPermutation(s);   
        }

    public static void displayPermutation(String s)
        {
        displayPermutation("", s);
        }

    public static void displayPermutation(String s1, String s2)
           {
        if (s2.length() == 0)
                   {
            System.out.println(s1);
                   }
            else
                   {
                for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
                   {
                   displayPermutation(s1 + s2.charAt(i), s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i+1));
                   }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just have 2 different method, with same name but different parameters, what specifically you don't understand ? The first one is just an nice wrapper to call the second

Comment: In your `main` method, user input is assigned to the variable `s`. `displayPermutation(s);` calls the `displayPermutation` with one parameter. This in turn calls the overloaded `displayPermutation` with two parameters using the values `""` (empty String) and `s`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For starters, `s1` and `s2` are confusing variable names. Call them `result` and `original` respectively and it may make more sense that you're building the result up char by char of the original string which shortens to approach the base case. On each frame, the loop takes every character remaining from the original string and adds it to the result string, recursing on every possibility, giving N! complexity. The reason for the overloaded wrapper is to relieve the original caller from having to specify `""`, the result string, which is an implementation detail.